Just got my brand new Indian passport with this mark on it

I just received my brand new reissued Indian passport today. The back page has this mark on it!  We are traveling in 3 weeks. Can I use it?

I think we’ve a similar question some time ago. This is a consequence of the process to punch those small holes through, it’s not uncommon to see a little bit of bleed/burn around those holes, though you probably have a little more than usual. I don’t think this would be a problem (as long as it doesn’t look like there was a manipulation of the hole pattern).

The holes are burnt; this is residue and perfectly normal.

I have a bunch of burn marks near my passports' holes, never had issues when traveling.

This question is similar to: Is my passport damage as it has this small minor dots on the top on the blank pages rest all the details are in good condition? Should I reissue?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
